# Selenium WebDriver not finding correct element with nodePath/text() method

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get a specific text element on a web app. I can't share the Html but the pertinent section looks something like this:

```
<div id ="user">
    <div class="large columns">         
                <label for="object.disabled" class="readOnlyClass  hide-label">
                    Text1
                </label>
                <div id="123x435q" class="readOnlyClass  hide">
                    <input class="disabled-field" id="123x435qs" type="text" value="07/20/2017" disabled="">
                </div>
    <div class="class1">
      <div>Text2</div>
    "

    07/10/2017
    "
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to find element.getText().trim() by xpath of //*[@id='user']/div[2]

I get result: Text2
07/10/2017

I'm trying to get just 07/10/2017 text. So I try xpath of //*[@id='user']/div[2]/text()[2]

When I run this in Chrome console: $x(//*[@id='user']/div[2]/text()[2]) I get my text node with a text attribute of 07/10/2017 (what I expect). However what I get when running through Selenium is: Text1.

So two questions: 
1. Why is path/text() returning Text1 in Selenium but not in Chrome console?
2. How can I get an element to return only the date text in the class1 div node and not return the Text2 text as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Selenium doesn't support TextNode. You can get 'Text1' because it is text of the element 'Label', while the 'Text2' is a TextNode inside the 'Div' element.

2 - You have to use other solutions to get the date text. See my example below.

```
String outerText = driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("#user > div.class1")).getText();
String innerText = driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("#user > div.class1 > div")).getText();
String dateText = outerText.replace(innerText,"");
```